# How to remove the global library from specific page??

Tags: 8, theming

How to remove the global library from specific page ?

I want to rearrange java script files.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement [hook_page_attachments_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments_alter/8.2.x).

Comment: Okay , how to check for that specific page ?

Comment: Here are some examples
https://www.drupal.org/node/2274705

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work for routes defined in module.routes.yml?

Comment: It doesn't matter. I just need to know the route name.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's very simple to use the Hook_page_attarchment_alter()
Please see the following code it may help you.

```
    function modulename_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments) {

    // Conditionally remove an asset.
    $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
    $result = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath($current_path);
    if ($result == "/<url slug>" ){
      if (in_array('<theme name>/global-styling', $attachments['#attached']['library'])) {
        $index = array_search('<theme name>/global-styling', $attachments['#attached']['library']);
        unset($attachments['#attached']['library'][$index]);
      }
    }

}
```